# PHP MySQL - User inputs name and corresponding id is inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `members` and `games`. In `members` is data such as `member_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, etc.

What I'm trying to do is create a form for `games`, where the user can input the first and last names of the member who participated (in one string, not separately) and some PHP code queries this name, finds the corresponding id and stores this instead. Of course, `member_id` is a foreign key in `games`, but the users aren't going to know the member's id, they will only know their name.

If anyone could explain how I might go about doing this I would greatly appreciate it.

Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="duration">Duration:</label>
        <input type="time" name="duration" id="duration">
    </p>
        <p>
        <label for="member_id">Member Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_id" id="member_id">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action:

```
<?php

// database connection
include 'pdo_config.php';

try {
// new pdo connection
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// prepare statement and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO games (date, duration, member_id)
  VALUES (:date, :duration, :member_id)");

$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt->bindParam(':duration', $duration);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);

// post data
$date = $_POST['date'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];
$member_id = $_POST['member_id'];

// execute statement
$stmt->execute();

// success or error message
echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

Ask the user to input the member name in the form instead of the member id. Then make a first query to the database to get the member id from the member name.

**Have in mind** that it's not a good idea to search the member id from its name, because you could have more than one member whit the same name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="duration">Duration:</label>
        <input type="time" name="duration" id="duration">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="member_name">Member Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_name" id="member_name">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

// database connection
include 'pdo_config.php';

try {
// new pdo connection
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// post data
$date = $_POST['date'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];

// Note that the explode only works well if user inputs one blank space to separate the name
// You can try to improve the separation method or better use two different inputs in the form

$nameArray = explode(" ", $_POST['member_name']);
$first_name = $nameArray[0];
$last_name = $nameArray[1];

$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
$statement->execute(array(':fisrt_name' => $first_name, ':last_name' => $last_name));
$row = $statement->fetch();

$member_id = $row['member_id'];


// prepare statement and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO games (date, duration, member_id)
  VALUES (:date, :duration, :member_id)");

$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt->bindParam(':duration', $duration);
$stmt->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);

// execute statement
$stmt->execute();

// success or error message
echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: @sinesine I couldn't try the code because I haven't got the database created. Please, let me know if it doesn't work for you and I'll try to fix it

Comment: No worries, thanks so much for your answer. I'm just going to test it now, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: `"Note that the explode only works well if user inputs one blank space to separate the name"`

I'm not sure what you mean here, are you saying the user will have to input the name with a space between the first and last name, like `John Smith` for it to work correctly? Would they input a name any other way? Like `JohnSmith` for example?

Comment: @sinesine There I was warning you that it would be better to use two different inputs in the form, for the first and last name (instead of only one string). Because if the user inputs, for example, two or three blank spaces it wouldn't work well. (Never trust the users...)

Comment: I see! That's good advice. The code works perfect by the way, thank you!